# Javascript on div added with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button "add" which add divs in a form.

In divs added, there'll be javascript too (1 select which depends on another select).

I'm using Symfony2, in order to add div I used Symfony's documentation :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $container = $('div#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails');
        var $addLink = $('<a href="#" id="add_type" class="">Ajouter un type</a>');
        $container.append($addLink);
        $addLink.click(function(e) {
            addSource($container);
            e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
            return false;
        });

        var index = $container.find(':input').length;

        if (index == 0) {
            addSource($container);
        } else {
            $container.children('div').each(function() {
                addDeleteLink($(this));
            });
        }

        function addSource($container) {
            var $prototype = $($container.attr('data-prototype').replace(/__name__label__/g, 'type n°' + (index+1))
                .replace(/__name__/g, index));

            addDeleteLink($prototype);
            $container.append($prototype);
            index++;
        }

        function addDeleteLink($prototype) {
            $deleteLink = $('<a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Supprimer</a>');

            $prototype.append($deleteLink);

            $deleteLink.click(function(e) {
                $prototype.remove();
                e.preventDefault(); // évite qu'un # apparaisse dans l'URL
                return false;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

And the javascript in the divs is :

```
<script>
    var $all = $('.type_js');
    $all.each(
        function () {
            $(this).change(function () {
                var parent = $(this).attr("id");
                var array_id = parent.split("_");
                var id = array_id[3];
                var $detail = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_'+id+'_detailType');
                $.post(" {{ path('updateDetailType') }}", { idType: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
                    $detail.find('option').remove();
                    if(data.length > 0) {
                        for (i in data) {
                            var option = $('<option></option>').attr('value', data[i][0]).text(data[i][1]);

                            $detail.append(option);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        var option2 = $('<option></option>').attr('value', null).text('-- Choisir une zone --');
                        $detail.append(option2);
                    }
                }, 'json');
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

Divs created via first script have a class 'type_js' which I use to have a change() call on each div with this class.

But If I create a div via first script, divs have the class 'type_js' but nothing is happening... I'm new to JS and JQuery, but I guess that Javascript is loaded when the page is created, and at this moment divs aren't there.

How would you do to make it work ? Is there a way to ask him to reload the javascript after calling first script ?

Thanks !

Comment: Use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach, when generating elements dynamically i.e. `$(document).on('change','.type_js', function(){  var parent = $(this).attr("id"); .....});`

Comment: @Satpal thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) :

```
<script>

    $(document).on("change", ".type_js", function () {

        var parent = $(this).attr("id");
        var array_id = parent.split("_");
        var id = array_id[3];
        var $detail = $('#mybundle_serveur_typesDetails_'+id+'_detailType');
        $.post(" {{ path('updateDetailType') }}", { idType: $(this).val()}, function (data) {
            //$zone.remove();
            //$quartier.clean();
            $detail.find('option').remove();
            if(data.length > 0) {
                for (i in data) {
                    var option = $('<option></option>').attr('value', data[i][0]).text(data[i][1]);

                    $detail.append(option);

                }
            }
            else {
                var option2 = $('<option></option>').attr('value', null).text('-- Choisir une zone --');
                $detail.append(option2);

            }
        }, 'json');
    });

</script>
```